# Weinberg QFT problem 2.1: transformation of quantum states

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, momentum, inertial-frames

I'm solving the following problem in Weinberg's QFT textbook: an observer sees a particle of spin 1 and mass $M$ move with momentum $\mathbf{p}$ in the $y$-direction, and spin $z$-component $\sigma$. A second observer moves relative to the first with velocity $\mathbf{v}$ in the z-direction. How does this second observer describe the particle's state?

My question is if there is an efficient way to solve this problem, because what I did took a while (and the problem looked a lot more innocent). Essentially what I did is:

1. Compute $\Lambda p$, where $\Lambda$ is the Lorentz transformation relating the two observers. This immediately gives us the momentum the second observer will measure for the particle.
2. Compute the standard transformation $L(p)$ that takes the standard momentum $k=(0,0,0,M)$ to $p$, the standard transformation $L(\Lambda p)$, and its inverse $L^{-1}(\Lambda p)$.
3. Compute the little group transformation $W=L^{-1}(\Lambda p) \Lambda L(p)$.
4. Notice that the above corresponds to a rotation by some angle $\theta$ around the x-axis (which makes sense), so we can write its representation matrix as $\exp(i\theta J^{(1)}_x)$, with $J_x^{(1)}$ the spin 1 representation matrix for angular momentum in the x direction.
5. Finally using the above matrix find the superposition of $\sigma$ states that the second observer will see.

As you can see, this is fairly lengthy (and even computationally tedious - I used Mathematica for some of it). I get the feeling there might be an easier way, but couldn't think of one. Any ideas?